# localizing datatable date inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm using datatable's date filter, but I can't change the language of the date.

I tried as below but it doesn't work. still in english.

```
 minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
        format: 'MMMM Do YYYY',
        locale: 'tr-TR',
        language: 'tr-TR,
        lang: 'tr-TR
    });
```

https://datatables.net/extensions/datetime/examples/integration/datatables.html

```
var minDate, maxDate;
 
// Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = minDate.val();
        var max = maxDate.val();
        var date = new Date( data[4] );
 
        if (
            ( min === null && max === null ) ||
            ( min === null && date <= max ) ||
            ( min <= date   && max === null ) ||
            ( min <= date   && date <= max )
        ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Create date inputs
    minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
        format: 'MMMM Do YYYY'
    });
    maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
        format: 'MMMM Do YYYY'
    });
 
    // DataTables initialisation
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 
    // Refilter the table
    $('#min, #max').on('change', function () {
        table.draw();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using the same libraries that are used in the [date range filter example](https://datatables.net/extensions/datetime/examples/integration/datatables.html) you linked to in your question - specifically:

- [the Moment library](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.2/moment.min.js) - more details [here](https://momentjs.com/)
- [the DataTables datetime library](https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.1.2/js/dataTables.dateTime.min.js) - more details [here](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/datetime)

You need to make 2 changes, shown below.

---

The **first change** is to replace the basic Moment library with the one which includes locale data:

```html
<!-- don't use this:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.2/moment.min.js"></script>
-->
<!-- use this instead: -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

This will allow your displayed dates to use localized (Turkish) values for month names.

Now, you should see data such as `Eylül 19 2022` in the input field, when you specify your locale:

```js
minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
  format: 'MMMM Do YYYY',
  locale: 'tr-TR'
});
```

The result:

[image]

---

The **second change** is to change the values which are displayed in the calendar selector. By default, the calendar will still use English month names and day-of-week abbreviations:

[image]

To fix this, you need to specify your localized data, as follows:

```js
var i18n_tr = {
    clear:    'Clear',
    previous: 'Previous',
    next:     'Next',
    months:   [ 'ocak', 'şubat', 'mart', 'nisan', 'mayıs', 'haziran', 'temmuz', 'ağustos', 'eylül', 'ekim', 'kasım', 'aralık' ],
    weekdays: [ 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat' ],
    amPm:     [ 'am', 'pm' ],
    hours:    'Hour',
    minutes:  'Minute',
    seconds:  'Second',
    unknown:  '-',
    today:    'Today'
};
```

In the above JavaScript object I have only translated the month names (apologies if I got that wrong).

You will need to translate the remaining text yourself, as needed.

You can then use this object in your date input code using `i18n` as its identifier:

```js
minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
  format: 'MMMM Do YYYY',
  locale: 'tr-TR',
  i18n: i18n_tr
});
```

Now the calendar will look like this:

[image]

And you will see a pick-list of Turkish month names if you click on `eylül`.

---

How did I know to use `i18n`? And how did I know what format is needed for its data structure?

This is defined in the DataTables [dateTime GUI code](https://github.com/DataTables/DateTime/blob/master/js/dataTables.dateTime.js#L1467) for the date picker.

There you can see all of the available defaults, including the `i18n` data structure.

Comment: thanks for your comment. your answer solved my issue. your detailed comment with i18n data structure is really helpful.